# Algorithm to transform a base 10 number to an any base number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, radix

I made this javascript program to convert base 10 number into another base number (smaller than 10). I would like to know why isn't the program responding.

```
Number to transform:<input type="text" id="number" /><br />
Base to transform to:<input type="text" id="basen" /><br />
<input type="submit" onclick="transform()" value="Transform" />
<script>
function transform()
{
    var i=0;
    var a;
    var b;
    var c;
    var e;
    var t=0;
    var pui;
    while(Math.pow(basen.value,i) <= number.value)
    {
        i++;
    }
    var pui=i-1;
    while(pui>=0)
    {
        a=1;
        while(Math.pow(basen.value,pui)*a <= number.value-t)
        {
            a++;
        }
        b=a-1;
        e=10^pui;
        t+=b*e;
        pui--;
    }
    document.write(pui);
}

</script>
```

Comment: The caret `^` does not mean power in Javascript.  It means exclusive-or.

Comment: Chrome DevTools makes debugging 300 times easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's pretty simple.

pui is an integer value.

Last time into the second loop is when pui = 0.

Then you decrement pui, making it -1.

Then you output pui, and that is where your -1 comes from ;)

Answer (score 4):

As Eric Jablow commented, `^` in JavaScript is a bitwise XOR operator. You want to use `Math.pow(number, power)` instead.

However, your whole algorithm could be replaced by the built-in [`Number.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString). for example:

```
(5).toString(4); // "11"
```

---

Also:

- You have a syntax error here:

  ```
  b=a-1:
       ^ -- should be a semicolon, not a colon
  ```

  This kind of error can be easily spotted if you keep your browser console open when testing.
- Your code relies on some magic performed by browsers, that automatically create variables based on HTML elements ID attributes. Don't do that, use `document.getElementById` to get element references.

Comment: I know I can do it with Number.toString but why is the algorithm always giving me the result: "-1" ??

Comment: @Sami Honestly, I don't understand the logic behind that algorithm, but I noticed that (a) every loop only runs once, and (b) there is no string manipulation there, and in JavaScript you can't represent numbers in other bases without strings.

Comment: isn't the while(pui>=0) repeating several times ??

Comment: Can you just explain to me why is it always giving the same answer "-1" ??

Comment: @SamiKhoury I dont know either, but I'll try to take a better look at the code tonight.

Comment: @SamiKhoury looks like DaveM nailed it.